# How to optimize MySQL query to find substring among three fields?

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL table fields:

`description1`, `description2`, `description3`: Varchar(500)

`value`: int

and wish to find the records where at least one of the description includes the `string` searched by the user.
Right now I am using the following query. It works, but it takes about 1.5 second to return the results.

```
SELECT `table`.`value`, 
      `table`.`description1`, 
      `table`.`description2`, 
      `table`.`description3`
      FROM `table`
WHERE ( `table`.`description1` LIKE '%string%'
OR `table`.`description2` LIKE '%string%'
OR `table`.`description3` LIKE '%string%' )
ORDER BY  `table`.`value` DESC LIMIT 0 , 9
```

Is there any way to get the results faster?

(Note that the `value` field is already indexed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add full text index and instead like use AGAINST

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did the fulltext index for the three description fields. But now with the query: "SELECT `table`.`value`,        `table`.`description1`,        `table`.`description2`,        `table`.`description3`       FROM `table` WHERE (  MATCH(`description1`) AGAINST ('string')  OR MATCH(`description2`) AGAINST ('string') OR MATCH(`description3`) AGAINST ('string') ) ORDER BY  `table`.`value` DESC LIMIT 0 , 9 ", I am getting completely different results than with my original query.

Comment: /*before*/ 
ALTER TABLE `table` ADD FULLTEXT (
`description1` ,
`description2` ,
`description3`
);
/*after*/
WHERE MATCH (description1,description2, description1) AGAINST ('string')

Comment: Yes, this is what I did. Though the results do not always include the 'string' exactly. If my string has three words, the results sometimes have two of the three words, etc. Is there a way to have exact matches of the substring?

Comment: please read: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html wit attention on `mysql> SELECT * FROM articles
    -> WHERE MATCH (title,body) AGAINST ('MySQL');` and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html